# how do I close window with handle using win32gui in Python

Tags: python, win32gui, window-handles

I have obtained the handle of a window I want to target, with win32gui library in Python

How do I close the window?

I have the following code, the second line did what I intended to do

but the last line seems to be wrong.

```
handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, r'Notepad++')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
win32gui.CloseWindow(handle)
```

I also want to know if I just want to close the window, is the second line necessary?

Besides that, I notice a minor thing, and I am curious about it:

If I try

```
win32gui.CloseWindow(handle)
```

in Python shell, I get something like:

```
2500276L
```

but if I try

```
handle = win32gui.CloseWindow(handle)
print handle
```

then I get

```
2500276
```

does the 'L' in the end make any difference?

Thanks for your attention!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
import win32con    
win32gui.PostMessage(handle,win32con.WM_CLOSE,0,0)
```

This should work.

Comment: does not work for me. wxpython window